# Locating birthplace of Herman Malies born around 1870 in Baden, Germany?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, birth-records, baden-wuerttemberg

I am looking for birth information for Herman Malies born around 1870 in Baden, Germany. I have found him in Camden New Jersey but cannot find any thing before that time.

Comment: You should tell us what you already know about him, and where (in which register) you found he was from Baden. Was he from the state baden or from the city Baden (today called Baden-Baden) whose the state's name comes from ?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! Malies is not a Baden surname, according to Geogen (German surname distribution). And Herman's US census records have him born in Germany (1905 NJ, 1910 US, 1915 NJ) or France (1930 US). That's consistent with Alsace-Lorraine, which was returned to France after WW1. But his immigration record (abt 1890) or naturalization (bef 1910) should have more information. Have you searched for those? (His WIFE was born in Baden, per 1930 US census).